# Any way to concatenate two Application setting in Configuration - Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

In Azure Function App, I have added two application settings using the Configuration tab. The first Application setting is fetching the SAS token from the Azure Key vault using @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=##). The other application setting is the endpoint URL. Now I have to concatenate these two variables and use in connection parameter in HTTP and Queue Trigger.
For example, Below StorageConnectionAppSetting will be the key that will have concatenated value.

```
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] string queueItem, ILogger log)
```

Is there any way this concatenation can be done in the Application setting itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. Even if you were to [customize configuration using DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources), it won't work for triggers when deploying to the consumption or premium plans as mentioned at the end of the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. As this option was not available, finally we had to keep the whole connection string in the key vault and access it using @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=)